# html agilitypack get data out of a table

Tags: .net, vb.net, html-agility-pack

what im trying to do is get the data out of this table:

```
<div class="fliptable">
<div class="head">
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
            Information</div>
    </div>
</div>
<table class="body">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="key" style="">
                SKU
            </td>
            <td class="right">
                SKU1<br>
                SKU2<br>
                SKU3<br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="key" style="">
                EAN
            </td>
            <td class="right" style="">
                EAN1<br>
                EAN2<br>
                EAN3<br>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

the code i have so far:

```
 Dim doc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
    doc.Load(WebBrowser1.DocumentStream)

    Try

        Dim key = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='fliptable']//table[@class='body']//tr//td[@class='key']")
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(key.InnerText & vbNewLine)

        Dim right As HtmlNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='fliptable']//table[@class='body']//tr//td[@class='right']")
        For Each p As HtmlNode In right.SelectNodes("//div[@class='fliptable']//table[@class='body']//tr//td[@class='right']//br")
            RichTextBox1.AppendText(p.PreviousSibling.InnerText.Trim() & vbNewLine)
        Next


    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

the results i get are:

```
SKU
SKU1
SKU2
SKU3
EAN1
EAN2
EAN3
```

what i would like:

```
SKU
SKU1
SKU2
SKU3
EAN
EAN1
EAN2
EAN3
```

but i cant for the life in me get it to work

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
Dim bodyTable = (From tbl In doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("table")
                Where tbl.Attributes.Contains("class") AndAlso tbl.Attributes("class").Value = "body").FirstOrDefault
If bodyTable IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim allTd = bodyTable.SelectNodes("//td")
    For Each td In allTd
        For Each token In td.InnerText.Split(New String() {}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            RichTextBox1.AppendText(token.Trim & Environment.NewLine)
        Next
    Next
End If
```